# caught error @ main DriverPackageNotInstalledError: Postgres package has not been found installed

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to start up my postgresql with typeorm on a node.js server and I'm getting this error: `caught error @ main DriverPackageNotInstalledError: Postgres package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install pg --save`

I've checked `pg` is installed in my docker container

deps versions:
`"pg": "^8.8.0",`
`"typeorm": "^0.2.34",`

My `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    profiles: ['api', 'web']
    container_name: slots-api
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
      target: dev
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 9229:9229 # for debugging
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/api
      - /app/node_modules/ # do not mount node_modules
      - /app/api/node_modules/ # do not mount node_modules
    depends_on:
      - database
    command: yarn dev:api

  database:
    container_name: slots-database
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    depends_on:
      - adminer
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: dev
      POSTGRES_HOST: 127.0.0.1
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

FROM node:16-alpine AS dev

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/ /app/
COPY . .
RUN yarn build:api

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

My typeorm config:

```
import { Connection, createConnection, DatabaseType } from 'typeorm';
import * as entities from '@/entities';
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

export const shouldCache = (): boolean => {
  return !['test', 'development'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV ?? '');
};

export default async function postgresConnection(): Promise<Connection> {
  const config = {
    database: 'dev',
    entities: Object.values(entities),
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 5432,
    type: 'postgres' as DatabaseType,
    username: 'admin',
    synchronize: false,
    dropSchema:
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
      process.env.POSTGRES_DROP_SCHEMA === 'true',
    migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.js'],
    migrationsRun: true,
    cache: shouldCache(),
  } as PostgresConnectionOptions;

  return await createConnection(config);
}
```

my `server.ts` file:

```
...
  await postgresConnection().then(async () => {
    console.info('Database connected!');
  });
...
```

It works without issues running the server locally, with the database and adminer running on docker

Comment: Are you overwriting node modules when you run `COPY . .`? Looking at package json doesn't verify anything is actually installed. Exec into the container and look at the downloaded modules

Comment: Yes that's what I did, inside my container I ran yarn list to see all the installed deps and then grep to search for "pg"

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file? Should you copy more than the app folder between docker layers?